# selecting repeated values from distinct group using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a Datatable as below and I want to select repeated names from other Classes

```
Name    Class
Akbar   1B
Akbar   1B
Amar    1A
Amar    1C
Antoney 1A
Bindhu  1B
Bindhu  1D
John    1C
Raj     1B
Bindhu  2A
```

Th result should be as below

```
Amar    1A
Amar    1C
Bindhu  1D
Bindhu  1B
Bindhu  2A
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance

Code

```
var dtStudents = new DataTable();
dtStudents.Columns.Add("StudentID", typeof(int));
dtStudents.Columns.Add("StudentName", typeof(string));
dtStudents.Columns.Add("Class", typeof(string));
dtStudents.Columns.Add("ContactNo", typeof(string));

DataRow drStudent = dtStudents.NewRow();

drStudent["StudentID"] = 1;
drStudent["StudentName"] = "Akbar";
drStudent["Class"] = "1B";
drStudent["ContactNo"] = "989878679";
dtStudents.Rows.Add(drStudent);

dtStudents.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Akabr", "1B", "989777" });
dtStudents.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Amar", "1A", "3453" });
dtStudents.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Amar", "1C", "543534" });
dtStudents.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Antoney", "1A", "54345" });
dtStudents.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, "Bindhu", "1B", "53453" });
dtStudents.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, "Bindhu", "1D", "3453453" });
dtStudents.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, "John", "1C", "3245345" });
dtStudents.Rows.Add(new object[] { 9, "Bindhu", "2A", "5345345" });

var results =
    from d in dtStudents.AsEnumerable()
    select d;

dataGridView1.DataSource = results.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Comment: Hi, what's the condition to select Amar 1A ?

Comment: Amar is found in 1A and 1C, Akabr is not required because it is found only in 1B. Bindhu Also found in two classed so bindhu also to be selected 1B and 1D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var results = dtStudents.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(
        x => x.Field<string>("StudentName"), // group by student name
        (k, xs) => xs.GroupBy(
            x1 => x1.Field<string>("Class"), // group by class
            (k1, xs1) => xs1.First())) // if there are duplicates, take only the first
    .Where(x => x.Count() >= 2) // remove if student only has one class
    .SelectMany(x => x); // flatten back to a single collection

dataGridView1.DataSource = results.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't really specify how you are connecting to your database so... regardless, let's assume you have some `IQueryable` called, I don't know, `classes`, or something.  Then you can do the following:

```
classes
.GroupBy(
    x => x.Name, 
    (key, values) => new { Name = key, Classes = values.Select(x => x.Class).Distinct())
.Where(x => x.Classes.Take(2).Count() == 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added my code for better clarity. Just want to filter the results where the same name is appearing in other classes but not in the same class

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this this way:

```
var results =
    dtStudents
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => new
        {
            StudentID = (int)x[0],
            StudentName = (string)x[1],
            Class = (string)x[2],
            ContactNo = (string)x[3],
        })
        .GroupBy(
            x => x.StudentName,
            (key, xs) => new 
            { 
                StudentName = key,
                Classes = xs.Select(x => x.Class).Distinct()
            })
        .Where(x => x.Classes.Skip(1).Any())
        .SelectMany(x => x.Classes
            .Select(y => new 
            { 
                StudentName = x.StudentName,
                Class = y
            }));
```